# CSS Column Layout displays differently in two browsers

Tags: html, css

I want to use the csscolumn layout for my work on both chrome and firefox browsers.on chrome it displays the correct layout(ex width-70% left and right 30%) but on firefox it displays incorrectly width 50% left and right.Can anyone help me in making this consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have a better way for this type of html structure you can try this and let me know if you have any issue or you can check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/FjMr3/
html code is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

css code is:

```
    .wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.left{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:70%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#06F;
}
.right{
    position:absolute;
    left:70%;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#0FF;
}
```